Builds for atypical templates using Electron + shadcn-ui not working as expected
I tried to create a simple app for desktop (windows) using electron + shadcn-ui. Everything was fine until the creation process, but I encountered a problem after the build.
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\fricle-v2> npm run build:win  

> fricle@1.0.0 build:win
> npm run build && electron-builder --win


> fricle@1.0.0 build
> npm run typecheck && electron-vite build


> fricle@1.0.0 typecheck
> npm run typecheck:node && npm run typecheck:web


> fricle@1.0.0 typecheck:node
> tsc --noEmit -p tsconfig.node.json --composite false


> fricle@1.0.0 typecheck:web
> tsc --noEmit -p tsconfig.web.json --composite false

vite v5.3.2 building SSR bundle for production...
✓ 2 modules transformed.
out/main/index.js 1.48 kB
✓ built in 351ms
vite v5.3.2 building SSR bundle for production...
✓ 1 modules transformed.
out/preload/index.js 0.42 kB
✓ built in 10ms
vite v5.3.2 building for production...
src/renderer/src/components/ui/dropdown-menu.tsx (1:0): Error when using sourcemap for reporting an error: Can't resolve original location of error.
✓ 1593 modules transformed.
../../out/renderer/index.html 0.54 kB
../../out/renderer/assets/index-CmxQvSOM.css 59.38 kB
../../out/renderer/assets/index-Bo_A_RzV.js 656.45 kB
✓ built in 2.44s
  - electron-builder version=24.13.3 os=10.0.22631
  - loaded configuration file=C:\Users\user\Desktop\fricle-v2\electron-builder.yml
  - writing effective config file=dist\builder-effective-config.yaml
  - "electron-squirrel-startup" dependency is not required for NSIS
  - skipped dependencies rebuild reason=npmRebuild is set to false
  - packaging platform=win32 arch=x64 electron=31.1.0 appOutDir=dist\win-unpacked
  - downloading url=https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v31.1.0/electron-v31.1.0-win32-x64.zip size=111 MB parts=8
  - downloaded url=https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v31.1.0/electron-v31.1.0-win32-x64.zip duration=19.518s
  - default Electron icon is used reason=application icon is not set
  - building target=nsis file=dist\fricle-1.0.0.exe archs=x64 oneClick=true perMachine=false
  - building block map blockMapFile=dist\fricle-1.0.0.exe.blockmap

The build succeeded with these messages,
I ran into a problem on a subsequent run.
I got an unexpected black screen instead of a normal screen.
I have no idea what this is caused by, and the project is built using the
atypical template, so I couldn't even be sure that it would work. If anyone knows how to get this to build properly, please help.
I expected :
expected
unexpected :
unexpected
github : https://github.com/aeirst/fricle
I'm Korean, so I translated it to DeepL.
